# Why combobox show error System.data.datarowview c#?

Tags: c#, combobox

I need to update the value of combobox machine name for the patient investigations, and when i retrieve the entered machine name from the database the following error always appeared system.data.datarowview.
This is my code:

1- The stored procedure :

```
create proc [GET_RESULT_MACHINES]
@Criteria nvarchar(20)
AS 
SELECT machines.machine_id , MACHINE_NAME AS 'MACHINE NAME'  FROM MACHINES
inner join LAB_RESULTS on LAB_RESULTS.machine_id = Machines.Machine_id
where CONVERT(varchar,[LAB_RESULTS].ORDER_ID) = ''+@Criteria+''
```

2- The class c# void:

```
public DataTable GET_RESULT_MACHINES(string Criteria)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Criteria", SqlDbType.VarChar,20);
            param[0].Value = Criteria;

            dt = DAL.SelectData("GET_RESULT_MACHINES", param);
            DAL.close();
            return dt;
        }
```

3- Key_Down void code when press Enter I am using the following code:

```
private void txtOrder_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"server= KAASH-AV-SRV; database=mamlakalab; Integrated Security=true; ");

            if (checkInitialResult.Checked == true && checkApproveResult.Checked == false && txtOrder.Text != string.Empty && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
            {
                dgvResult.DataSource = result.GetOrderForResult(txtOrder.Text);

                comboMachines.DataSource = result.GET_RESULT_MACHINES(txtOrder.Text);
                comboMachines.DisplayMember = "MACHINE_NAME";
                comboMachines.ValueMember = "machine_id";
            }
}
```

I checked the previous questions but i cannot find the answer 
your suggestions please.

Comment: i'm guessing that the problem is in your `DisplayMember` property. In your stored procedure, you're using alias `MACHINE NAME` and you're binding `DisplayMember` to `MACHINE_NAME` (with underscore).

Comment: correct thank you working. But I have another issue now in combo box i need to update the value but with this code its show me only the selected value and not show the other machine names how to modify the code to show the selected value from the database plus all machine names that i can change the machine name?

Comment: your combo shows only one value because your stored procedure returns just one record.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was remove the underscore from machine name thank you Nino

```
private void txtOrder_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"server= KAASH-AV-SRV; database=mamlakalab; Integrated Security=true; ");

            if (checkInitialResult.Checked == true && checkApproveResult.Checked == false && txtOrder.Text != string.Empty && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
            {
                dgvResult.DataSource = result.GetOrderForResult(txtOrder.Text);

                comboMachines.DataSource = result.GET_RESULT_MACHINES(txtOrder.Text);
                comboMachines.DisplayMember = "MACHINE NAME";
                comboMachines.ValueMember = "machine_id";
            }
}
```